# How to Map nested Object in using a map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object

I am trying to map a nested object in React. This is how my object currently looks like

```
  "data": {
    "user1": {
      "Public": [
        1,
        0
      ],
      "Team Only": [
        1,
        1
      ],
      "All": [
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    "user2": {
      "Public": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "Team Only": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "All": [
        0,
        0
      ]
    },
```

The way I am trying to map it is like this

```js
    const TableRows = (obj) => {
        const userObject = Object.entries(obj);
        const row = userObject.map((owner, mainIndex)=> {
          return (
            <TableRow key={console.log(`row-record-${owner[1]}`)} highlightOnHover={true}>
              {Object.entries(owner[1]).map((value, index) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={console.log(`column-value-${value}`)}
                  alignmentHorizontal={
                    tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent] &&
                    props.componentName != "Open_COE_Default"
                      ? tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent][index]
                      : index != 0
                        ? "center"
                        : ""
                  }
                >
                 {owner[1]} // This prints out user1, 11,11 expected is user1, 1, 1

                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          );
        });
        return row;
      };
```

The issue I am encountering is that when I do run this in the UI, the expected output should be something like

```
user1, 1, 1
user2, 1, 1
```

But instead the output turns out like this

```
user1, 11,11
user2, 22,22
```

Now I am unsure why it is taking the two separate values for 1 and 1 and then meshing them together. Is the way I am mapping not correct or am I not using the right keys for the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code seems to be that you're not accessing the individual elements of the value array correctly when rendering the `<TableCell>` component. Instead of `owner[1]` in the `<TableCell>` component, you should use `value[1][0]` for the first element and `value[1][1]` for the second element, like this:

**EDITED CODE**

```js
const TableRows = (obj) => {
  const userObject = Object.entries(obj);
  const row = userObject.map((owner, mainIndex)=> {
    return (
      <TableRow key={console.log(`row-record-${owner[1]}`)} highlightOnHover={true}>
        {Object.entries(owner[1]).map((value, index) => (
          <TableCell
            key={console.log(`column-value-${value}`)}
            alignmentHorizontal={
              tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent] &&
              props.componentName != "Open_COE_Default"
                ? tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent][index]
                : index != 0
                  ? "center"
                  : ""
            }
          >
            {value[1][0]}, {value[1][1]}
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    );
  });
  return row;
};
```

This should render the expected output:

```bash
user1, 1, 1
user2, 0, 0
```

Note that `value[1]` is an array with two elements, `value[1][0]` corresponds to the first element in the array `(e.g., 1)`, and `value[1][1]` corresponds to the second element in the array `(e.g., 0)`.

Comment: Using `value[1]` is to the same effect. It seems it still prints out 11,11 instead of 1 , 1, Could I be looping wrong and not calling the values properly?

Comment: That could be the reason. I would suggest, that you could reframe your question again, this might help people to understand it better. Maybe with a `code snippet` or a valid `JSFiddle link`.

Comment: Can you try the edited answer now @ZubairAmjad, and let me know whether this works?

Comment: Yes it does work, one last question and this is my fault for not being specific in the question. Will update the question accordingly. Lets say I am want to choose between `Public`, `Team Only` and `All`. How would I be able to do that, the current solution seems to pick one and displays the data for that specific one, is there a way to add one of those keys accordingly in order to access whichever one is picked

Comment: Glad it works for you now @ZubairAmjad. If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to choose between the keys `Public`, `Team Only`, and `All` and display the corresponding values for each user. One way to achieve this is to **add a state variable in your component to keep track of the selected key, and then use that selected key to access the corresponding value for each user in the TableRows function**. I'd really appreciate it if you mark this as correct and upvote this answer, for better solution accessibility to the problem.

Comment: That makes sense, my question is how would I be able to access that key? For instance when I log out the result of value, I get two arrays one with the key and one with the response. How would I go about accessing each key in that case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253076/discussion-between-zubair-amjad-and-alok).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const TableRows = (obj) => {
    const userObject = Object.entries(obj);
    const row = userObject.map((owner, mainIndex)=> {
        return (
        <TableRow key={console.log(`row-record-${owner[1]}`)} highlightOnHover={true}>
            {Object.entries(owner[1]).map(([value, index]) => (
            <TableCell
                key={console.log(`column-value-${value}`)}
                alignmentHorizontal={
                tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent] &&
                props.componentName != "Open_COE_Default"
                    ? tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent][index]
                    : index != 0
                    ? "center"
                    : ""
                }
            >
                {value}{Object.entries(index).map(([key, val]) => (<>, {val[0]}</>))}
                
            </TableCell>
            ))}
        </TableRow>
        );
    });
    return row;
};
```

expected Output:

```
user1, 1, 1, 1
user2, 0, 0, 0
```